# use a function which return table, hibernate, postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, stored-functions

I have a working stored function on postgresql db

```
create or replace function sp1(d1 date, d2 date)
returns table(ServiceType varchar, counter bigint) as $$
begin
return query select servicerequesttype, count(*)as counter from events 
where creationdate>=d1 and creationdate<=d2
group by servicerequesttype 
order by(counter) desc;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

which returns a table with two columns, varchar and bigint. I execute it like

```
select * from sp1();
```

Now I want to use this on hibernate. As I understand I want to execute a raw query on hibernate and create a List for the result.

Is this possible, or I have to rewrite the stored procedures all over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view in the database and then in Java code, you can query view 
This is a technique used when you have complex queries or aggregated values.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "V_SERVICE_VIEW")
public class ServiceView {
..
..
}
```

Comment: Yes, but each time I execute the function I change the parameters. The view will have all the previous values or it will be empty?